# How to write textbox values to .txt file with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, text-files

I have a simple form with two textboxes, I want `Textbox1` to write to a file named `C:\VALUE1.txt` and `Textbox2` to write its value to a file named `C:\VALUE2.txt`

Any text that is already in the text file MUST be over written.

Answer (score 17):

It's worth being familiar with both methods:

1) In VB.Net you have the quick and easy My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText option:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\value1.txt", TextBox1.Text, False)
```

2) Or else you can go the "long" way round and use the StreamWriter object. Create one as follows - set **false** in the constructor tells it you don't want to append:

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\value1.txt", False)
```

then write text to the file as follows:

```
objWriter.WriteLine(Textbox1.Text)
objWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\VALUE2.txt"
If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
  Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
  objWriter.Write(TextBox2.Text)
  objWriter.Close()
  MsgBox("Text written to file")
Else
  MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `System.IO` and `System.Text` namespaces, in particular the `StreamWriter` object.