# How to save a content of a specific textbox to file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, savefiledialog

Good morning everyone,
I'm working on my finals project in visual basic and i want to implement a save file option.

Right now the application has 2 textboxes (not richtextbox) which are the input and output of information.

What i want to do is save only the content of the output textbox. I managed to get it to save something to file but when its opened it always turns out to be empty.

the code example of the save file button is below, i have a feeling its not saving the content because it is not specified, yet i have no idea how to specify to only save the content of the one textbox even with the many hours of forum / google searching ive done to try and figure out on my own.

```
        Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim nsavetxtoutput As New SaveFileDialog()
    '|All files (*.*)|*.*
    nsavetxtoutput.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.text"
    nsavetxtoutput.FilterIndex = 2
    nsavetxtoutput.RestoreDirectory = True

    If nsavetxtoutput.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = nsavetxtoutput.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' Code to write the stream goes here.
            myStream.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

Any and all insight would be much appreciated!

Thank you guys!

---

The Program allowed to save only the contents of the textbox with this function - Thanks very much everyone who replied. it helped out allot!

```
Private Sub NOTEPAD_BUTTON(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTSave2Notepad.Click
    Dim nsavetxtoutput As New SaveFileDialog()
    nsavetxtoutput.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.text"
    nsavetxtoutput.FilterIndex = 2
    nsavetxtoutput.RestoreDirectory = True

    If nsavetxtoutput.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        IO.File.WriteAllText(nsavetxtoutput.FileName, txtoutput.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically the only thing i want the function to do is save the specific information of one of the 2 textboxes. Then allow the user to save it with a name of his choice and path of his choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write textbox values to .txt file with vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002529/how-to-write-textbox-values-to-txt-file-with-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
If nsavetxtoutput.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    IO.File.WriteAllText(nsavetxtoutput.FileName, TextBox2.Text)
End If
```

Where `TextBox2` is your output TextBox.

More information at [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Function worked like a charm! had to remove the savefiledialog option open because it was asing to input a second but now it saves the output content without any problems! Thanks sysdragon :D

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file using `File.WriteAllText` method. It takes two parameters. The first is the path to the file, which you get from the `SaveFileDialog`. The second is the value you want to write to the file.

[See the article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i believe we have a winner! ill try this and ill get back to you. :P