# how to Write Content into textfile in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I Created VALIDCCC.TXT and I need to write some content into this text file, content as shown below

Content :

```
00   A0
00   A1
00   A2
10   A0
10   A1
```

My Code as Follows :

```
filepath = filepath + "\" + strsubmenu + "\"

If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(filepath)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath)
End If

filepath = filepath + "MATRIX\"
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(filepath)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath) 
End If

filepath = filepath + "VALIDCCC.TXT"
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(filepath)) Then
    File.Create(filepath)
End If

File.WriteAllText(filepath, String.Empty)
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath, True)

For Each Customeritem As ListItem In CustomerCodeDVListBox.Items

   For Each CCCitem As ListItem In CCCListBox.Items 
       objWriter.WriteLine(Customeritem.ToString() + Space(4) + CCCitem.ToString()) 
   Next
Next
```

I have 2 listboxes combination of this listbox seleted values should write into Textfile.
Before writing content if VALIDCCC.TXT exists I need to clear the content or overwrite with New Content...

Comment: There are dozens of questions here with answers regarding writing text to files from vb.net, including those that explain appending vs. truncating. Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002529/62576), for instance. The second parameter to `StreamWriter` decides which is done, which the documentation clearly explains.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002529/how-to-write-textbox-values-to-txt-file-with-vb-net                                             when I implement the same its throwing error : "The Process cannot Access the File because it is being used by another process. vb.net"

Comment: That's because you create the same file with `File.Create`. Read your own code. You need to use `File` or `StreamWriter`, but you can't do both at the same time on the same file.

Comment: even File.OpenWrite also showing the same error can you guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working ...

```
 filepath = filepath + "VALIDCCC.TXT"
                Dim objWriter As StreamWriter

                Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                For Each Customeritem As ListItem In CustomerCodeDVListBox.Items
                    If Customeritem.Selected Then
                        For Each CCCitem As ListItem In CCCListBox.Items
                            If CCCitem.Selected Then
                                sb.Append(Customeritem.ToString() + Space(4) + CCCitem.ToString())
                                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine) 
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

                If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(filepath)) Then
                    objWriter = File.CreateText(filepath)
                    objWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
                    objWriter.Close()
                End If
```

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps:

```
filepath = filepath + "\" + strsubmenu + "\MATRIX\VALIDCCC.TXT"
Dim DirPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
If Not Directory.Exists(dirpath) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirpath)
End If
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath)

For Each Customeritem As ListItem In CustomerCodeDVListBox.Items

   For Each CCCitem As ListItem In CCCListBox.Items 
       objWriter.WriteLine(Customeritem.ToString() + Space(4) + CCCitem.ToString()) 
   Next
Next
```

This will create any folders as necessary and overwrite or create the text file as needed.