# nvarchar data type in sql not supported math type character

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I want to insert multi language, and math type uni character throw rich text box,
in sql nvarchar data type.

But it does not support certain character like mention below in picture red circle.

After that i got it throw crystal report show in green box but its changed?[image]

Comment: Same font in CR right?

Comment: have you explored other alternatives like storing the red-circled characters in your application's my.settings as an image (that is, if you won't use it for any calculation) or as a file on your hard disk? Please let us know how these turned out for you. Thanks

Comment: yes same font in red circle is not saved in sql

Comment: currently i am not using it for any calculation but may be in future storing as image file another option i have any other idea or picture is best solution ?

Comment: First, use some commas in your question text - it is very hard to understand. Second, set "Text interpretation" in field format options as "RTF".

Comment: where can i set this  set? "Text interpretation" in field format options as "RTF". sory not yo use comma

Comment: let me see...since you can get the text into a rich textbox control (which accepts .RTF format), i believe you can export the text to a notepad and store it in your application directory. That might be an easier way than the image suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing my previous post or adding a new comment, but i needed to have 50 reputations for the that. So, if this post is bypassing any rules, forgive me as i had to help the OP.

I believe one or more of these links should be of help:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?700133-RESOLVED-Copy-RTF-to-Clipboard-but-it-will-not-paste-to-notepad

[How to write textbox values to .txt file with vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002529/how-to-write-textbox-values-to-txt-file-with-vb-net)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f7cf2c4-47dc-467e-add9-dd7b2be84249/writing-text-to-notepad-with-visual-basic?forum=Vsexpressvb

Let us know how it turned out for you. Remember to mark as answered if it helped you.