# how to write to .txt file in UWP vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, uwp, text-files

i am trying to have a .txt file containing a single line with a number on it. i need this txt file to be editable by the program and to be installed with it.
the .txt file will be completely overwritten when the number needs to be replaced.

how can i do this? all other tutorials refer to C# or JS I need vb.NET

Comment: Convert the C#, there are many online converters.

Comment: can you give an example? @OneFineDay

Comment: http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write textbox values to .txt file with vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002529/how-to-write-textbox-values-to-txt-file-with-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [Create, write, and read a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) topic about interaction with file in `UWP`.

To write string to `StorageFile` use `FileIO.WriteTextAsync` or `FileIO.AppendTextAsync` functions

```
Dim file As StorageFile = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("file.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
Dim strData As String = "sample text to write"
Await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, strData)
```